# System Generator: How to generate a .bit file?

Tags: fpga, xilinx, xilinx-system-generator

I am using System Generator and I would like to generate a .bit file in order to load into my FPGA. Does anyone know how to generate a .bit file with SG?
Thank you.

Comment: Could anyone create a tag called how-to or suggest me one synonymous?

Comment: meta tags are bad.  Anyone that knows [fpga]'s or  specifically about [xilinx] products and keeps track of those tags might be able to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I found the how-to.
Just click on the System Generator token block on the simulink scheme and configure its parameters. In the parameter  compilation it´s neccesary to select 'bitstream'.